# For all $x>0$ $\frac{1}{x+1}\le\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})\le\frac{1}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x>0$. can we deduce from:
$$
\forall t\in [x,x+1]: \frac{1}{x+1}\le\frac{1}{t}\le\frac{1}{x}
$$
that
$$
\frac{1}{x+1}\le\ln(1+\frac{1}{x})\le\frac{1}{x}
$$

Comment: Yes, for sure :  $\int_{x}^{x+1}\frac{dt}{t}=\log(x+1)-\log(x)$ by definition of $\log$. Then $\log(x+1)-\log(x)=\log (\frac{x+1}{x})=\log(1+\frac{1}{x})$

Comment: The confusion here might arise from the fact that $t$ is variable and $x$ is fixed, whereas usually $x$ is variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x>0$. Note that $x$ is a fixed constant. Suppose further that,
$$ \forall t\in [x,x+1]: \frac{1}{x+1}\le\frac{1}{t}\le\frac{1}{x}. $$

Then,

$$ \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{1}{x+1} dt \leq \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{1}{t} dt \leq \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{1}{x} dt $$

$$ \implies \frac{1}{x+1}\le\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\le\frac{1}{x}$$

[image]

There is no trickery in the final step: it is just standard integration. The source of confusion might be that $\ x\ $ is a constant here, whereas usually $\ x\ $ is a variable.